# I try to create new app with next JS, but I get this error:

Tags: npm, next.js

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\OSONN\Desktop\nextjsapp/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\OSONN\Desktop\nextjsapp\package.json' 
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\OSONN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-14T22_38_16_128Z-debug-0.log
```

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\OSONN\Desktop\nextjsapp/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\OSONN\Desktop\nextjsapp\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\OSONN\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-14T22_38_16_128Z-debug-0.log

Comment: how to you create the project? what command are you using?

Comment: this is not first project for me with nextjs, i use npx create-next-app@latest , I make sure that the mistake is not in the way the project is created